# ¿Como obtener el nombre de un archivo seleccionado en un p:fileupload de primefaces antes de que se presione el botón subir?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Estoy trabajando con un p:fileupload en modo avanzado usando primefaces lo que pretendo es mandar un mensaje al momento de seleccionar un archivo sin necesidad de presionar el boton subir o upload, recién comenece a trabajar con jsf y primefaces, estuve revisando las propiedades o atributos de la tag fileupload y no encontre alguno que me ayudara, espero me puedan ayudar con alguna idea de como hacerlo de antemano, gracias.

Comment: Con primefaces podrás obtener información del archivo hasta que se llegue al servidor(uploaded). Podrías intentar con JQuery obtener el nombre.

Comment: Antes que nada gracias por comentar, y si es lo que estoy checando, al momento de seleccionar el archivo si no me equivoco se guardan en una tabla temporal,  lo que no se es si se podría obtener el valor de la td de esa tabla?